# How to customize NSTextField look (Font used, font size) in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstextfield

I'm making a Cocoa application and I can't figure out how to do something.

I want to make an NSTextField with a custom look like the one in Wallet :

[Wallet screenshot.](http://kttns.org/nlyzn)

I figured out how to change the NSTextField size but I don't know how to change the font and it size. I subclassed NSTextFieldCell like this but it doesn't work, the font is not changed if I don't choose a system font and the size only change line height but not characters height.

Header file :

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface VLTextFieldCell : NSTextFieldCell {
}
@end
```

Class file :

```
#import "VLTextFieldCell.h"

@implementation VLTextFieldCell

- (NSFont *)font
{
    return [NSFont fontWithName:@"Lucida Grande" size:16.0];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To change the font of an NSTextField, change its font in Interface Builder using the Font Panel, or via -setFont: at runtime.

It is not necessary to subclass NSTextField or NSTextFieldCell simply to use a different font.

Comment: Oh right… I was looking for the Font setting… Didn't think about the +T Font Panel.
Thanks ;)

Comment: One is NOT able to set the font in this manner in xCode 4.1 / 4.2.  Don't let this guy make you feel crazy...  The panel is missing.  And the "normal" font panel has no effect on any built product.

Comment: When I wrote this answer in 2009, Xcode 4.x didn't exist. However, you still can set the font for an NSTextField in Interface Builder: http://cl.ly/1I3T3E1D3o1X2b0E0u0x

Answer (score 7):

```
[label setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldItalicMT" size:20]];
```

`setFont:` is declared in `NSControl`, super class of `NSTextField`.